# Error reading voices installed on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, text-to-speech

I use this code to read the installed speech synthesizer:

```
System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer oVoice = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
```

But in debugging I see that it generates an error:

```
oVoice threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'
```

So when I run the next line of code:

```
var oV = oVoice.GetInstalledVoices();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
No entry installed on the system or no entry available with the current security setting.
```

But I have three voices installed, I checked in the control panel and tried them.
I don't understand why I get these errors.
I use Windows 10 Enterprise, Visual Studio 2010 (I have 2019 but I can't use it now) and Framework 4.0 (and I can't change it).

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET Framework 4.0? It's 10 years out of date! That's probably the problem in the first place. Why can't you target .NET Framework 4.7.2. or 4.8 - or .NET Core 3.0?

Comment: There are some dlls that work well only with version 4, it doesn't depend on me, I had this limit from my company.